# Javascript. Replace HTML content of a Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So I am currently building a website where when you click on a small image it displays bigger above. Along with the image being enlarged text overlays the image describing it and I can't seem to get the code to change the text right. The text is more complicated as it uses spans etc so i have to place HTML code to and it just displays the text without the formatting.

```js
    // Image 1 - Football
function change1() {
    document
        .getElementById("mainPic")
        .src = "http://files.stv.tv/imagebase/170/623x349/170248-lossiemouth-fc.jpg"
    ;
    document
        .getElementById("imageCaption")
        .innerHTML = "<span>Lossiemouth Football Club<span class='spacer'></span><br /><span class='spacer'></span>Come watch a game of football!</span>"
    ;
}

// Image 2 - Football
function change2() {
    document
        .getElementById("mainPic")
        .src = "http://www.visitscotland.com/wsimgs/Course%206_704927777.JPG[ProductMain]"
    ;
    document
        .getElementById("imageCaption")
        .innerHTML = "<span>Golf Course<span class='spacer'></span><br /><span class='spacer'></span>Come play a couple rounds of golf!</span>"
    ;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageCaption">
    <h2 align="left" style="padding-left: 105px;">
        <span>Lossiemouth Football Club
            <span class="spacer"></span>
            <br />
            <span class="spacer"></span>
            Come watch a game of football!
        </span>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Screen shot examples:
Before
[image]
After
[image]

Comment: I don’t see what the missing “formatting” should be. What’s the expected result? Also… are you aware of the “[ProductMain]” at the end of the second URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the `<h2>` tag. Just move your id to that tag or create a new id and use it to set `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

The code you are inserting with the javascript is different than the code that is initially in the div. `change1()`

```
<h2 align="left" style="padding-left: 105px;"><span>Lossiemouth Football Club<span class="spacer"></span><br /><span class="spacer"></span>Come watch a game of football!</span></h2>
```

is becoming

```
<span>Lossiemouth Football Club<span class='spacer'></span><br /><span class='spacer'></span>Come watch a game of football!</span>
```

You need to either add the `<h2>` tag or change what you reference with `document.getElementById`